# Ruby on Rails undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have the following setup:

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :categories
  has_many :products
end
```

**categories_controller.rb**

```
def show
end

private
  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title, :category_id)
  end
```

**products_controller.rb**

```
def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:title, :price, :text, :category_id, :avatar)
end
```

**Category show**

```
<% @category.products.each do |p| %>

   <article class="content-block">
      <h3><%= @p.title %></h3>
   </article>

<% end %>
```

And this returns the error in the title. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be :

```
<h3><%= p.title %></h3> # as, your block variable is p, not @p
```

NOT

```
<h3><%= @p.title %></h3>
```

One more suggestion, you could write your `set_category` method, as:

```
def set_category
  @category = Category.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
end
```

It will solve [N + 1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) problems using *Eager Loading Associations* technique.